# Azure Log Analytics Cross-Workspace using watchlist

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to have a quick overview on last heartbeats from all the workspaces we have.
Now, I can do that with this query, except for the watchlist line, because it uses the watchlist from the workspace where I'm doing the query, not from each of the other workspaces:

```
union
workspace("<workspace_id1").Heartbeat,
workspace("<workspace_id2").Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(timeRange)
| where not (Computer in ( (_GetWatchlist('<watchlist_name>') | project SearchKey)) )
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated,*) by Computer, OSType
```

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Anyone from Microsoft can answer here please?